# AzureFunctionApp(TimerTrigger) Lock files when copy inside azure file share folders

Tags: azure, azure-functions

i have two azure functions that are going to copy files inside a folder in azure file share and paste them inside other folder.

i have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var file = results2.ToList()[i];

    if (file is CloudFile cloudFile)
    {
        var fileName = cloudFile.Name;
        log.LogInformation($"Function({invocationId}) | Trying to move File: {fileName}");

        var copyFile = folderToDir.GetFileReference(fileName);

        await Task.WhenAll(copyFile.CreateAsync(cloudFile.Properties.Length), copyFile.StartCopyAsync(cloudFile)).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Function({invocationId}) | Copied File: {fileName}");
                cloudFile.DeleteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                log.LogDebug($"Function({invocationId}) | Failed to copy file ({fileName}). Try again");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can i lock the file that one azure function is currently moving so the other one don't process the same file, to avoid concurrency.

Comment: Question: why do you have 2 functions doing the same thing then? Either make sure they both process different files or folders or make a single function or put items to move on a queue so other functions can do the work.

Comment: @PeterBons, i can make only one function but due to the large files i need to process i need to scale up my function to have two or more instances running at the same time. So i will get the same problem

Comment: How many files are we talking about? How do you get the list? What is `results2`? Please tell us more about the context, like how are the functions triggered.

Comment: We are talking around 10000 files, this is a TimerTrigger function that every 20 seconds trigger. This ```results2 ```is a IReadOnlyCollection of the files that im retrieving this way:
```var files = await folderFromDir.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync(null);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the timer trigger to gather the files by calling `ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync`. Then have it distribute the work to other functions to process the files.

You could for example divide the result of `ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync` into small buckets and call another Azure Function providing a bucket to process. Multiple function invocations will then process all the files together.

You can use the [fan-out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#fan-in-out) of durable functions for this as well:

[image]